# VSCode run all go tests in folder with launch configuration

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to make a launch configuration that will run all of the `go` tests I have in a specific folder in my repo.

I can successfully run `go test ./src/...` in the terminal to run all the tests I care about but I'm having trouble replicating that in a VSCode launch configuration.

Here's my current launch configuration:

```
        {
            "name": "run tests",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "test",
            "args": ["./src..."],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}",
        }
```

It seems that using `./src/...` as args doesn't behave as I expect it to. Using this launch configuration I get an error that:

```
no Go files in /home/paymahn/gadic/backend
exit status 1
Process exiting with code: 1
```

Is there a way to replicate `go test ./src/...` as a VSCode launch configuration?

Comment: launch.json is used to configure the debug target, and `test` mode corresponds to `dlv test` which takes a single package or a single go file as args. So, `./src/...` isn't a valid arg for delve. (See `dlv help test` for usage).

Consider `tasks.json` instead. https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/tasks.md

Comment: Ah gotcha, that's super helpful. I'll take a look at `tasks.json`

Answer (score 0):

When I try to run a simple test I use this setting, [reference here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go/issues/318#issuecomment-217063523).

```json
{
    "name": "Tests",
    "type": "go",
    "request": "launch",
    "mode": "test",
    "remotePath": "",
    "program": "${fileDirname}",
    "env": {},
    "args": ["^TestGenerateConfigurationFailure$"]
}
```

And about the specific folder, I understand that the Golang test tool inspects the "test" module package. No, the specific regex name folder for the Golang test tool.

You can check more info in official debugging VS-Code for Golang [HERE](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/debugging.md)